# Error al conectar firebase y Vuejs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

Estoy conectando Vuejs y Firebase con vuefire. En el archivo main.js hago lo que se indica:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

//Firebase

import VueFire from 'vuefire'

Vue.use(VueFire);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Al levantar el servidor en local me da el siguiente error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined

No encuentro lo que puede ser

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te falta la configuracion de los creadenciales de firebase

```
import { firestorePlugin } from "vuefire";

Vue.use(vuetify);
Vue.use(firebase);
Vue.use(firestorePlugin);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify: new vuetify(),
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

y debes poner la configuracion en el file App.vue

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
var firebaseConfig = {your credentials};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```